# Sending JSON over serial in Python to Arduino

Tags: python, c++, json, arduino, pyserial

I've been trying to set up this sample snippet for communicating over Serial with Python. I intend to send a simple JSON packet and de-serialise it over the other end with an Arduino.

But the JSON Library taken from [here](https://arduinojson.org/v6/doc/deserialization/) throws an error of Invalid Input.

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  while(!Serial) {
  }
}

void loop() {
  int     size_ = 0;
  char    payload[256];
  String  string = "";
  if (size_ = Serial.available()) {
  for(int i =0; i < size_; i++) {
     payload[i] = Serial.read();
     string += payload[i];   
  }

  const size_t capacity = 1024;
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(capacity);
  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload);
  if (error) {
    Serial.println(error.c_str());
    return;
  }
    if(doc["operation"] == "ACK") {
      Serial.println("ACK has been received");
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("Error!");
    }
  }
  while (!Serial.available()) {
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

This is the python snippet.

```
import time
import json
import serial
import pprint


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("Ready...")
    data = {}
    data["operation"] = "ACK"
    ser = serial.Serial("COM3", baudrate= 115200, timeout=0.5)
    data = json.dumps(data)
    if ser.isOpen(): 
        (ser.write(bytes(data, "utf-8"), ))
        try:
            incoming = ser.readline().decode("utf-8")
            print ((incoming))
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
        ser.close()
    else:
        print ("opening error")
```

For some reason I can't figure out why, when python sends over the chunk it doesn't seem to recognise the input.

> Is it because of the 'b' added infront of it?
>   Is it because of the encoding method used?

When i try to input `{"operation":"ACK"}` via the terminal, it recognises it perfectly, and sends back a success message.

Why isn't it working over python? [ I am using Python 3 ]

[UPDATE]
I tried to change a bit of the python code to do some debugging.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("Ready...")
    data = {}
    data["operation"] = "ACK"
    ser = serial.Serial("COM3", baudrate= 115200, timeout=1)
    data = json.dumps(data)
    buf = []

    if ser.isOpen():
        for x in (data):
            buf.append(ord(x))

        ser.write(bytearray(buf))
        try:
            incoming = ser.readline()
            for x in incoming:
                print ((x))
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
        ser.close()
    else:
        print ("opening error")
```

and changed the Arduino script to send back the string it received.

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  while(!Serial) {
  }
}

void loop() {
  int     size_ = 0;
  char    payload[256];
  String  string = "";
  while (size_ = Serial.available()) {
  for(int i =0; i < size_; i++) {
     payload[i] = Serial.read();
     string += payload[i];   
  }

  const size_t capacity = 1024;
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(capacity);
  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload);
  if (error) {
    //Serial.println(error.c_str());
    Serial.print(string.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length() ; i++) {
      Serial.write(string[i]);
    }
    return;
  }
    if(doc["operation"] == "ACK") {
      Serial.println("ACK has been received");
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("Error!");
    }
  }
  while (!Serial.available()) {
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

This is the python output.

```
Ready...

50
50
240
240
123
34
111
112
101
114
97
116
105
111
110
34
58
32
34
65
67
75
34
125
```

As you can see the size is printed twice right after the "ready..." and there are two chars of value 240 sent from the Arduino. I don't understand why there are these two chars in the front.

Comment: Seems like this hinges on the actual data the arduino receives to try to decode - can you edit it into your question? If you're using Python 3, then yes a b' on the string won't be recognised because it's not valid JSON - you will almost certainly need  need to encode the string to ascii before transmission.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? 2.7 or 3? Check this link to find the version
https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/chapter_01/osx_setup.html

Comment: @barny yes, its python 3. Could you please drop a sample of what your trying to say?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you should edit into your question an example of exactly what your code outputs/tries to send to the arduino to decode. Looking at it (or perhaps trying to decode it yourself using python) will almost certainly answer your question.

Comment: All you've got to do is write `bytes(data, "utf-8")` to file, then examine the file.

Comment: What is the precise error? You say "it doesn't seem to recognise the input" - is there an error, or nothing at all?

Comment: @jfowkes There are two possible points of failure, either Arduino or from Pythons end. 

When I meant error, in the first Arduino Script, it prints the deserialization error. 
After a little bit of debugging, I find out that Arduino is sending out 2 chars in the front, of ASCII value 240. Please check the updated question.

Comment: It looks like something is encoding your string as UTF8. Those `240` chars look like continuation bytes. Try using `ser.write(data.encode('ascii'))` instead of using the byte array.

Comment: @jfowkes it still adds the `240` chars infront.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a while of figuring out what the problem was, There were couple of issues.

- The baud-rate was too fast, I had to reduce it down to 9600.
- The encoding from python was supposed to be sent as ASCII.
- On Arduino reading the string until '\n' was needed.
- Statically allocating the JsonDocument to 512 bytes worked.

  The arduino JSON-[Assistant](https://arduinojson.org/v6/assistant/) has a method of finding out the require allocation for the architecture used.

The python code below.

```
import time
import json
import serial
from pprint import pprint
import random

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("Ready...")
    ser  = serial.Serial("COM3", baudrate= 9600, 
           timeout=2.5, 
           parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, 
           bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, 
           stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
        )
    data = {}
    data["operation"] = "sequence"

    data=json.dumps(data)
    print (data)
    if ser.isOpen():
        ser.write(data.encode('ascii'))
        ser.flush()
        try:
            incoming = ser.readline().decode("utf-8")
            print (incoming)
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            pass
        ser.close()
    else:
        print ("opening error")
```

The arduino code.

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  while(!Serial) {
  }
}

void loop() {
  int     size_ = 0;
  String  payload;
  while ( !Serial.available()  ){}
  if ( Serial.available() )
    payload = Serial.readStringUntil( '\n' );
  StaticJsonDocument<512> doc;

  DeserializationError   error = deserializeJson(doc, payload);
  if (error) {
    Serial.println(error.c_str()); 
    return;
  }
  if (doc["operation"] == "sequence") {
     Serial.println("{\"Success\":\"True\"}");
  }
  else {
      Serial.println("{\"Success\":\"False\"}");
   }
  delay(20);
}
```

Hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: On python side, read the json using `myJson = json.loads(incoming)`